# Unique finite measure on $\sigma(\mathfrak{A})$ (an algebra of sets)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have a statement of a Theorem (possibly some formulation of the Hahn-Kolmogarov theorem?) in my notes as follows:

> Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be an algebra of subsets of $X$ and let $\mu_1,
>  \mu_2$ be finite measures on $\sigma(\mathfrak{A})$. If $\mu_1(A) =
>  \mu_2(A)$ for all $A \in \mathfrak{A}$, then $\mu_1 = \mu_2$.

The sketch of the proof I have is this:

> Define $\mathfrak{M} = \{A \in \sigma(\mathfrak{A}) : \mu_1(A) = 
> \mu_2(A)\}$. Then $\mathfrak{M}$ is a monotone collection containing
>   $\mathfrak{A}$. Let $m(\mathfrak{A})$ denote the the monotone
>   collection generated by $\mathfrak{A}$. Then $\mathfrak{M} \supseteq
> m(\mathfrak{A}) = \sigma(\mathfrak{A})$.

I’m following all of this.

However, then my notes say:

> The result follows from the fact that $\mathfrak{M} = \sigma(\mathfrak{A})$.

I don’t see how that gives the result we need. I would appreciate any clarity on this!

Comment: It is a consequence of monotone class theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem.